# magento 2 module register event observer

Tags: magento2, event-observer, core-config-data

Is there a way to do some action at module **registration/installation**?

It can be through event observer or through migration.

I want to call a function to get some values and store them in **core_config_data** during installation.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use *InstallData.php* to store value in core_config_data during installation

use below code for example :

```
$configdata = [
                'scope' => DEFINE_YOUR_SCOPE
                'scope_id' => 0,
                'path' => DEFINE_YOUR_PATH
                'value' => YOUR_VALUE,
            ];
 $setup->getConnection()->insertOnDuplicate($setup->getTable('core_config_data'), $configdata, ['value']);
```

Comment: Thanks @Hariharan. I want to also do some action (call an api using this config values as parameters) during installation. Can you help?

Comment: Not sure. you can try to create a new function to call api for testing in InstallData.php and call into install function

Answer (score 0):

Try to save config values via `config.xml`

**First Method:**

> app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Store:etc/config.xsd">
    <default>
        <sectionName>
            <groupName>
                <fieldName>add value here</fieldName>
            </groupName>
        </sectionName>
    </default>
</config>
```

**For eg.**

```
<default>
    <payment>
        <checkmo>
            <active>1</active>
            <order_status>pending</order_status>
            <title>Check / Money order</title>
        </checkmo>
    </payment>
</default>
```

**Second Method:**

```
<?php
namespace VendorName\ModuleName\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

/**
 * @codeCoverageIgnore
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CouplingBetweenObjects)
 */
class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
   public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
   {

        $data = [
            'scope' => 'default',
            'scope_id' => 0,
            'path' => "{section-name}/{group-name}/{field-name}",
            'value' => "Value",
        ];
        $setup->getConnection()
            ->insertOnDuplicate($setup->getTable('core_config_data'), $data, ['value']);
    }
}
```

**After run below commands:**

- php bin/magento setup:upgrade
- php bin/magento setup:di:compile
- php bin/magento cache:clean

Comment: Thanks @Abdul. The idea is to collect some store information and store them into  the config data and use them as a parameter to call an api during module installation. Is this possilbe?